# How to build compass in sublime text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I [downloaded this package](https://github.com/WhatWeDo/Sublime-Text-2-Compass-Build-System) which allows use to build compass in though sublime text by pressing `cmd+b`.

I created a sass file, made sure compass is selected from the tools > build system > compass menu. But when I press `cmd+b` the file does not compile and I get no error. I only get `[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]`.

However I also tested to build the code with sass (tools > build system > sass) and it works fine. Do I need to do anything to the sass file for compass to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue, and although this question is about a month old now, thought I'd leave my findings here for the next person who finds this question. I suspect that you, like me, may have a different directory structure than is explicitly supported by the SL2 package in question. If config.rb is anywhere other than the project root or in the same directory as the .sass or .scss file, it will fail to build, and because it matches no options, it will provide no output and take a vanishingly small amount of time.

My solution was to add a third statement to the command which checks the parent directory, which I committed to [my fork of the plugin](https://github.com/netaustin/Sublime-Text-2-Compass-Build-System) and submitted as a pull request.

Hope this helps somebody!